# Detecting Matlab failure to solve sparse linear system

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I want to programmatically find out when A\b failed (for sparse A) so that I can run some problem-specific logic. Using the backslash operator

```
A\b
```

I get warnings printed to the console but I want to know about these conditions (singular or nearly singular) programmatically so I can do some problem-specific stuff.

For *dense* systems, I can do

```
[soln, cond_recip] = linsolve(A,b);
if cond_recip < 1e-15, ..., end
```

But linsolve does not work for sparse matrices and I do not want to densify my matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
%# temporarily set warning to issue errors (maybe there are others?)
s = warning('error', 'MATLAB:nearlySingularMatrix'); %#ok<CTPCT>

try
    x = magic(4)\[34; 34; 34; 34];
catch ME
    disp(ME.message)
    %#.. problem specific stuff..
end

%# restore warning state
warning(s);
```

Comment: I learned of this trick from: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently/